# Cartesian product of an indexed family of sets

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

I'm reading Classic Set Theory for Guided Independent Study, and it gives this definition:
[image: 1]

I don't really understand.
"Given $a_i\in A_i$ for each $i\in I$" means that if $I$ is for example $ℤ$, we have ...$a_{-1}\in A_{-1}$, $a_0\in A_0$, $a_1\in A_1$, ...
Does this mean that each $A_i$ has only one element $a_i$?

"the sequence $<a_i>_{i\in I}$  is the function $f:I\rightarrow⋃\{A_i:i\in I\}$ where $f(i)=a_i$" so that means that given a number $i$ in $ℤ$ this function gives us an element of $A_i$, so $a_i$".

"the cartesian product of the indexed family of sets $\{A_i:i\in I\}$ is the set of all such sequences" so it means that the cartesian product is the set of all these functions, but i don't really see how.

The book just gives an "example":
[image: 2]

but i don't get it, first thing, by my understanding of the definition, $A_i$ has one element, $a_i$, and here has infinite elements (the elements of the interval of $ℝ$ $(i,i+1)$) so i'm confused already, because, for example $A_1=(1,2)$, what is then $a_1$? Any element in that interval?  And the function $f(i)=a_i$ for each $i\in I$? how is $<i+1/4>$ a function $f:$ℤ$\rightarrow⋃\{A_i:i\in $ℤ$\}$ where $f(i)=<i+1/4>$?

Could you guys make my ideas a little clearer and maybe give me a simple example like, with $I=\{1,2\}$, $A_1=\{v, w\}$ and $A_2=\{x, y\}$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to add some context. What we want to do is generalize the familiar concept of finite sequences and finite Cartesian products. For example, from the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ we can make the Cartesian product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, which consists of tuples $(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. A finite sequence here could be the tuple $(3,5)$, which would be the function $f: \{ 1,2 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$f(1)=3, \quad f(2)=5$

In that way, we have that $f \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. In a similar manner, we can define an inifinite Cartesian product by letting the index set be for example the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. An element of such should be familiar to you as a sequence $(x_1,x_2,...,)$, seen in for example convergent sequences of numbers in analysis or calculus. For example, a sequence could be

$(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, ...)$

This sequence is then in the language presented to you here the function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$f(i) = \frac{1}{i^2}$

The set of all sequences is then denoted $\prod_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$.

So you see, the sets are not one element sets, but just sets where you can choose an element from to make a sequence. Does this make sense to you, or is it as confusing as the definitions you posted yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand the first part but i have a doubt on the second part, the function $f:ℕ\rightarrowℝ$ given by $f(i)=1/i^2$ would only give all the values from $1$ to (almost) $0$, but if this defines one sequence, how can you define another one? if "the formula" is just $f(i)=1/i^2$? what is the "set of all sequences"?

Comment: Yes, this just defines one particular sequence. The set of all sequences here would be all the functions $f:  \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.